# phpunit.xml Does not seem to be working

Tags: php, configuration, phpunit

I have bee trying to get this test to run

```
require_once 'PHPUnit/Framework.php';
require_once('../config/config.php');
require_once('../classes/division.class.php');

class DivisionTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function Divisiontest()
    { 
     $division = new division();
     try{
      $division->createDivisionDetails();
     }catch (CustomException $e) {
   return;
  }
     $this->fail('An expected exception has not been raised.');
    }

}
```

on this Command

phpunit --configuration=phpunit.xml division.test.php

but keep geting the error message

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: HTTP_HOST in /home/workspace/people_scope/config/config.php on line 13

Notice: Undefined index: HTTP_HOST in /home/workspace/people_scope/config/config.php on line 13
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: HTTP_HOST in /home/workspace/people_scope/config/config.php on line 26

Notice: Undefined index: HTTP_HOST in /home/workspace/people_scope/config/config.php on line 26
PHP Warning:  require_once(/people_scope/config/standard.inc.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/workspace/people_scope/config/config.php on line 46

Warning: require_once(/people_scope/config/standard.inc.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/workspace/people_scope/config/config.php on line 46
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/people_scope/config/standard.inc.php' (include_path='/usr/bin:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear:/people_scope/assets/PEAR/:/people_scope/classes/base/') in /home/workspace/people_scope/config/config.php on line 46

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/people_scope/config/standard.inc.php' (include_path='/usr/bin:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear:/people_scope/assets/PEAR/:/people_scope/classes/base/') in /home/workspace/people_scope/config/config.php on line 46
```

I am using a phpunit.xml to try to set the $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] but seem like it is not working at all

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<phpunit>
        <php>
                <server name="HTTP_HOST" value="DEV"/>
        </php>
</phpunit>
```

Everything I have read seem to say this should work

Comment: Hi Jazzjazzy,

Can you please let me know were your phpunit.xml file is stored?

Comment: How did you solve the problem? I have a similar issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The xml looks fine as far as i can see it. Two suggestions:

```
class DivisionTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function Divisiontest()
```

i'd change the function name to `testDivision()` so phpunit picks it up as a real test (the code gets execution because its named like the class (a.k.a. php 4 style constructor) but thats not really optimal)

If that doesn't fix your problem: Does it work when you put

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = "DEV";
```

before the

```
$division = new division();
```

statement ? Just to make sure the error is that the xml file isn't read and doesn't hide somewhere else

Comment: had a try, first part didn't work there was no change, but if I put $_SERVER at the top of the pages works fine, which is a not really what I was looking for.

Comment: Just wanted to make your the problem really is that the configuration isn't read (there is no chance any code unsets this value ?) -- Also: What do you mean by "at the top of the pages" ? The unittest ?